# Label every nth datapoint in ggplot

Tags: r

I am wanting to plot changes in weight(X) per day(Y). I would like to label the very first datapoint, then every seventh.

I am currently using `geom_point() + geom_label(aes(label = weight))`. I was thinking maybe `rep()` would do this, but I can't figure out how; if it even will.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: By "the very first datapoint, then every seventh" do you mean 1, 7, 14... or 1, 8, 15... ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994202/label-every-nth-element-in-ggplot-depending-on-row-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147849/how-to-show-every-second-r-ggplot2-x-axis-label-value

Comment: @neilfws, 1, 7, 14, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the data to `geom_label` and filter for row numbers that match your condition.

Assuming that by "every seventh" you mean 7, 14, 21... use `%% 7 == 0`. Otherwise use `%% 7 == 1` for 8, 15, 22...

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- data.frame(x = 2 * (1:49), 
                     y = 3 * (1:49))

mydata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_label(aes(label = x), 
             data = . %>% 
               filter(row_number() %% 7 == 0 | row_number() == 1))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I used `filter(row_number() %% 7 == 1 | row_number() == 1))` and this got me what I needed: eg. the first Monday, then every consecutive Monday.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data = data.frame(timecount = 1:210,
                     value = 1:210 + 20*sin((1:30)/10))

library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)

my_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(timecount, value)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  filter(row %% 7 == 1) %>%   # modulo operator: only keep rows
                              # where the remainder of row / 7 is 1,
                              # i.e.  1, 8, 15, etc.
  ggplot(aes(timecount, value)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]